# How to pass StaticResources to a ViewModel in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

My application (MVVM Light) resizes it's main window (hides and shows it with an animation). For the animation I use a DataTrigger with parameters from StaticResources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <system:Double x:Key="WindowMaxWidth">400</system:Double>
    <system:Double x:Key="WindowMinWidth">25</system:Double>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Window">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DropBox.IsShown}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                             To="{StaticResource WindowMaxWidth}"
                                             Duration="0:0:0:0.2"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                             To="{StaticResource WindowMinWidth}"
                                             Duration="0:0:0:0.2"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Style>
```

In my ViewModel I need my window's width value, so I bound it. The problem is that it's 0 by default, so I have to initialize it with a value. Actually what need is the value form my static resources: **WindowMaxWidth**.

1. I can't move the value of WindowMaxWidth to ViewModel because DataTriggr doesn't accept bindings (it complains about threads)
2. I don't want to keep the same value separately in StaticResources and ViewModel to avoid incoherence.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `WindowMaxWidth` and `WindowMinWidth` in your viewmodel and reference them with `x:Static`:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
   class ViewModel
   {
      public static double WindowMaxWidth = 400;
      public static double WindowMinWidth = 25;
   }
}
```

Import the right namespace `xmlns:myns="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"`

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
    To="{x:Static myns:ViewModel.WindowMaxWidth}"
    Duration="0:0:0:0.2"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use code behind in such way (for instance in constructor, after you set DataContext to ViewModel):

```
(this.DataContext as MyViewModel).MyWindowWidth = (double)this.FindResource("WindowMaxWidth");
```